# Dividing string including whitespace blocks

Tags: python, regex, string

Does exist a command such that splits a string in a way that the whitespaces become a string too?. For example, suppose that the command is "coolsplit":

```
>>> example='hey,    whats up,     how are you?'
>>> example.coolsplit()
    ['hey,','   ','whats',' ','up,','     ','how',' ','are',' ','you?']
```

Does it exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) capturing the delimiter:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> re.split(r'(\s+)', example)
['hey,', '    ', 'whats', ' ', 'up,', '     ', 'how', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'you?']
```

`\s+` here means "one or more whitespace characters", parenthesis define a [saving group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping).